# Show date on x-axis and datetime when the user hovers on d3 chart

Tags: datetime, d3.js

I am trying to create a simple line chart with datetime at interval of 5 minutes on the X-axis and some data on the Y-axis, 
the data is getting displayed as intended when the chart is displayed, however it shows the date and time both on the X-axis. 
I just want to show the dates on the X-axis at one day interval and the both (date & time) inside the chart when user hovers on the data points.

I have put the following code for the "XAxis" attribute inside options section:

```
        xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Date',
                    tickFormat: function (d) {                           
                        return d3.time.format('%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')(new Date(d))
                    }
```

Please suggest on how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can stay with default formatting, it is quite intelligent for almost every case.
But for force formatting use in your case use `"%a %d"`.

To show tooltip you do not have to add format to axis, you have to do smth like:

```
    someD3Elements.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    return tooltipElement.style("visibility", "visible")
      .text(function() {
        return d3.time.format('%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y')(new Date(d));
      });
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    var event = d3.event;
    return tooltipElement.style("top", (event.pageY) + "px").style("left", event.pageX + 10 + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    return tooltipElement.style("visibility", "hidden");
  })
```

where `someD3Elements` could be e.g. circles, and `tooltipElement` could be defined smth like:

```
tooltip = d3.select("#viewPort")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .text("");
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer, but for example, if the received data contains data for 5 days, then it should create a scale for those five days with a gap of 1 day. And it should show the time for that day and the data for it inside the chart when user hovers on the data points line.

Comment: onhover event does not linked to the scale format, you should process them differently. I do not see the problem what you are facing. May be it will be better if you provide full code, jsfiddle and screenshots?